# how to get which <html:submit> button is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two `<html:submit>` buttons for validating both buttons by using common method form on `submit()`, both submit buttons are same value "save" how can I get  which button is clicked in JavaScript for the purpose of separate validations..

Comment: you can use this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

using onclick attribute to check different validation:

```
<input type="submit" value="save" onclick="validate1();"/>
<input type="submit" value="save" onclick="validate2();"/>
```

and do different validation in two function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form onsubmit="alert(this.submited); return false;">
    <input onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" type="submit" value="save" />
    <input onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dj3QE/24/)

Answer (score 0):

With eg. jQuery you can utilize the target attribute that gets sent in the click()-function:

```
$( 'button' ).click(function( event ) {
  console.log(event.target.nodeName );
});
```

Comment: jQuery wasn't tagged in the question.

Comment: well the same logic works in pretty much every javascript framework